# Why does material textures get applied on native Unity game objects, but not my imported Blender FBX?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender

I have created a basic standard Unity cube, but also imported a Blender FBX.

I drag and drop a material with a texture, on both the cube and the Blender model.

As you can see, the cube gets the texture, but the Blender model just becomes red, with no texture.

Why doesn't the Blender model adopt the texture? What have I missed?

Ive checked the "Material" settings on both objects, and it seems the same.

Seems like its a fundamental setting I have missed, so only colors and not textures are applied.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wall is a Blender model, right? You need to unwrap the UV of that model in Blender so Unity knows how to map the texture to the model. There are plenty of tutorials on that topic on Youtube, like https://youtu.be/V6OXSR5Ynyc.